# Click needsclick elementbyid

Tags: javascript

Here is the HTML

```
<select style="width:100%;" class="needsclick" id="order_billing_country" name="order[billing_country]" tabindex="-1">
                        <option value="USA" selected="selected">United States</option>
                        <option value="CANADA">Canada</option>
                      </select>
```

I have done the following which works;

```
document.getElementById("order_billing_country").value = 'CANADA'
document.getElementById("order_billing_country").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

HOWEVER, I need to dispatch an Event that clicks it, because when you click the country, the box with states changes to provinces, but so far my solution doesn't change the states box to provinces.

This does nothing;

```
document.getElementById("order_billing_country").dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
```

When you also select CANADA, they update the total amount, but my solution doesn't work.

Also how do I translate this;

```
$('#size-options').find('option#large').prop('selected', true);
```

into a working Javascript command so I can use it in Swift such as;

```
.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"todo\")[(itemIndex)].click()", completionHandler: nil)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try onchange: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp so add something like <input id="order_billing_country" onchange="updateStates()" />

Comment: @XTOTHEL, I am scrapping a website and using dispatchEvent 'onchange' does nothing :(